# How do you avoid getting rusty at applied math after univeristy

Tags: soft-question

As a new postdoc working in a bio-math interface discipline, I often wish I had more formal math training than my math minor many years back. Compared to others who came from more of a math/physics/engineering background, I would like to 1) retain and improve my proficiency in basic math (linear algebra, differential equations) and 2) gain more confidence in tackling new problems that require original analytical derivations.

I'm currently trying to spend 1hr/day just doing problems or going through lectures online. However, I have never heard of anyone else, grad students or postdocs, who make this sort of effort to keep up their level of math prowess. Am I being really absurd and should just focus on my immediate career tasks and stick to my strong suit instead of wasting time on daily math workout?

Comment: Totally off topic, but I felt like my heart skipped a beat after reading "wasting my time on daily math workout".

Comment: I may expand this comment into an answer, but for starters, how about answering questions here on MSE as a way to practice?  Works for me!  Cheers!

Comment: There is an indetermination principle at play here. You have two poles:focus on your task, the one you are paid for, and losing the opportunity to learn new and master old mathematics, and spend time on general mathematical workout, at the risk of dispersing your concentration and your time. The right way is of course to find the delicate equilibrium between the two. This is arguably the hardest part of a PhD-postdoc program, for me at least.

Comment: Off-the-cuff "advice":  keep at it.  'Mos 'def *not* a waste of time! Also, nice question, ***endorsed!*** More Cheers!

Comment: @Giuseppe That is the dilemma.

Comment: It's applied math, find a way to apply it!

Comment: I learned in statistics that if you ask a biased audience you will not get an objective answer.  The people who come hear believe in spending their time on a daily math workout and will encourage you to do the same (not at the expense of your career of course).

Comment: @AmyB this is a catch-22 statement. Either hope the site of math-enthusiasts can tell you how to stay good at math, do math!, or go somewhere without math enthusiasts and have them tell you, something else? Either way the Op will be spending time with math!

Comment: If it helps you feel better, I recently got a PhD in math and am doing a postdoc in computer science.  I'm still trying to learn more math (especially the stuff I was never good at--abstract algebra) and learn more stats (because it is useful).  That's part of why I spend time on here... if you ever feel "comfortable" with your level of understanding you'll probably start to slip.  The idea is to always be stretching yourself.

Comment: @RobertLewis It would be great if you can expand on that. Why is contributing to MSE a "better" way to practice than going through problem sets, other than helping the community of course?